# Linq extension methods - how to obtain parent object?

Tags: c#, linq, object, extension-methods, parent

My database looks like that: (it's pseudocode)

```
public class thread
{
   int id;
   List<Post> Posts;
}

public class Post
{
   int id;
}
```

As input, i have post id, and i want to know in what thread is that post. Can i do it with extension methods for linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you mean the following:

```
var myThread = threads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Posts.Any(p => p.id == somePostId));
```

This would return the first (if any) matching `thread` instance which contains a post with the given  post id or `null` if no instance matches. This assumes you have a collection `threads` of `thread` instances exposed e.g. using Linq to Entities.

In general I would try to avoid class names that conflict with existing class names in the .NET framework (like `Thread`).

Comment: But consider a situation, when i don't have thread id, but only a post id, so how could i obtain thread it?